# how can i write a simple file downloader in c language?

Tags: c, download

hello i have to download a simple .txt file from web in c language.

i have found a way with curl ([tut](http://prasanthmadhavan.wordpress.com/2010/12/17/libcurl-with-c/)) but now i want to know other ways.
my application should check the content of file and return it.

filecontent:

```
open
```

or

```
closed
```

Does someone knows any tutorials or codesnippets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a tutorial about sockets and have to look up the HTTP spec. It's pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

I always fine [the Beej's Guide to Network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) a good guide. The reading of the [HTTP rfc](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) will help too.